Why were these tagging suggested edits rejected?
I submitted a bunch of suggested edits to retag questions from website to more specific tags for the web app they pertained to.
Four of these were rejected claiming "The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing."
Why? My understanding of this site's tagging policy is that all web apps with at least one question deserve their own tag, and others (i.e https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/137755/revisions) seem to agree.

None of the tags included any guidance for how they can be used and added little value to the site, except for creating work for reviewers.

You flagged this for closure
You added a tag to this without checking that it was a web app as the link was broken. I subsequently determined that the URL had changed and updated it.
This is not a web app and is a question about saving bookmarks (Super User) even if it was a web app.

